device id value changed after upgrading to android version to 14 in flutter app
I'm working on attendance flutter app Each time I open the App to check in or check out the App signs me out saying I am logged in on another device although (That's mean the device ID is different about that is saving in the database)  this is not true, note: I'm using device info pulse 9.1.2 package. this issue happening only with android 14 and when installing the App from google play  but doesn't happen if I use the application by Apk version
I hope someone can help me with this issue.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I recommend not relying on any OS device ID but storing your own UUID on the first app start and storing that in your database.
Anything related to identifying a specific device is not recommended today because of privacy reasons.

@raina if you accept this as answer, please mark the answer as accepted so that other users know this is solved
